# C++20 template lambdas with template parameter that is not related to function parameters

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

I have array of tuples.
I'm sorting it.
I can choose which field to use for sorting at runtime.

```
switch (columnIndex)
{
case 0:
    std::ranges::sort(rows, [reversed](const rowType& a, const rowType& b) -> bool {
        if (reversed)
        {
            return std::get<0>(a) < std::get<0>(b);
        }
        return std::get<0>(a) > std::get<0>(b);
    });
    break;
    break;
case 2:
    std::ranges::sort(rows, [reversed](const rowType& a, const rowType& b) -> bool {
        if (reversed)
        {
            return std::get<2>(a) > std::get<2>(b);
        }
        return std::get<2>(a) < std::get<2>(b);
    });
    break;
case 3:
    std::ranges::sort(rows, [reversed](const rowType& a, const rowType& b) -> bool {
        if (reversed)
        {
            return std::get<3>(a) > std::get<3>(b);
        }
        return std::get<3>(a) < std::get<3>(b);
    });
    break;
}
```

(don't mind missing case 1)

I wanted to replace all that code with using c++20 template lambdas, so I don't have to repeat that lambda 3 times.
I made a lambda that could work for this purpose.

```
using rowType = std::tuple<size_t, const char*, unsigned int, unsigned int>;
bool reversed = false; // this is just an example of input I may have
auto sortLambda = [reversed]<size_t tupleIndex>(const rowType& a,
                                                const rowType& b) -> bool {
    if (reversed)
    {
        return std::get<tupleIndex>(a) < std::get<tupleIndex>(b);
    }
    return std::get<tupleIndex>(a) > std::get<tupleIndex>(b);
};
```

But I can't pass it to sort.
There's no syntax I have found that allows me to specify template parameter to specialize lambda and then pass it in sort.
I don't see any way to use lambda which have template parameter, in case if that template parameter is not used in function parameters.

So I need to use lambda to capture reversed flag, it's messy to do it with functions.
But I also need template parameter to select which tuple index I want to compare.
How can I rewrite that code to use single lambda (or to get rid of repetition any other way)?

Is there any way to actually call my template lambda? Because I can't find syntax that would allow me to specify template argument manually for lambda, but if I don't specify it manually it can't deduce it automatically.

(In case there's difference between compilers I'm using Visual C++ 2019)

Comment: can you post reproducible example?

Comment: I updated code so template lambda should compile now.
As for other code, sample would be too big and probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the lambda you can write a functor template:

```
template <size_t index> 
struct comparator {
    bool reversed;
    bool operator()(const rowType& a, const rowType& b) const {
        if (reversed) {
            return std::get<index>(a) < std::get<index>(b);
        }
        return std::get<index>(a) > std::get<index>(b);
    }            
 };
```

And use that with `sort`:

```
std::sort(begin,end, comparator<0>{reversed});
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/z6GYTGP9r).

Note that you need the switch anyhow when `columnIndex` is only known at runtime.

I don't think having the lambda with a template parameter that cannot be deduced from paramters is actually useful here (well, see below). As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322668/4117728) explains, its the lamdbas `operator()` that is a template, and typically the template paramters get deduced inside `sort`, only when `operator()` is called. On the other hand, in the above template you can fix the template parameter before passing an instantiation to `std::sort` and inside `sort` an ordinary `operator()` is called.

---

I was curious to see how this can be done with only lambdas, defined only in local scope. Inspried by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322668/4117728):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

using rowType = std::tuple<int,int>;

int main(){

    bool reversed = false;
    auto comparator_generator = [reversed]<size_t index>(){
        return [reversed](const rowType& a, const rowType& b){
            if (reversed) {
                return std::get<index>(a) < std::get<index>(b);
            }
            return std::get<index>(a) > std::get<index>(b);
        };
    };

    std::vector<rowType> x;
    std::sort(x.begin(),x.end(),comparator_generator.operator()<0>());
}
```

Syntax looks a little funny. `comparator_generator.operator()<0>()` calls the outer lambda to get the inner one which is the actual comparator. This again nicely illustrates that it is `operator()` that is the template.

Comment: That's basically a closure from js. And it seems there's no way to avoid it if I choose to go lambda way.

Comment: @Devaniti js ? I dont understand what you want to "avoid". You need to fix the index somewhere somehow, thats not something you can avoid

Comment: Concept of wrapping function in another function to hide some kind of argument inside is clouse, JavaScript is one of the languages where it's common. I don't want to avoid it, it just seems that there's no easier way to do this with lambdas.

Comment: @Devaniti the second part of the answer is just a curiosity. Imho writing the functor is more readable. What you get from `comparator_generator.operator()<0>()` or `comparator<0>{reversed}` is basically identical. Only downside of the first is that you cannot define a template inside a function.

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand what happens. You create the lambda with templated `operator ()` - not a lambda template. There is no such thing as specialising lambda and pass it elsewhere.

You can wrap the lambda in other lambdas and customizer the wrapping it depending on column index. Or you can just create a regular class template - it is simple and straightforward enough in your case.

Comment: Now I get it.
sortLambda.operator()<0>(rows[0], rows[1]); successfully cals it.
sadly it's probably unusable as lambda for sorting though.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:

```
template<auto x>
using constant_t=std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, x>;
template<auto x>
constexpr constant_t<x> constant={};
```

it is now really easy to pass a compile time constant to a lambda.

```
using rowType = std::tuple<size_t, const char*, unsigned int, unsigned int>;
bool reversed = false; // this is just an example of input I may have
auto sortLambda = [reversed](auto tupleIndex){
  return [reversed, tupleIndex](const rowType& a, const rowType& b) -> bool {
    if (reversed)
    {
      return std::get<tupleIndex>(a) < std::get<tupleIndex>(b);
    }
    return std::get<tupleIndex>(a) > std::get<tupleIndex>(b);
  };
};
```

then just do

```
std::vector<rowType> x;
std::sort(x.begin(),x.end(),sortLambda(constant<0>));
```

The trick is that `constant<0>` is an integral constant, and it has a constexpr casting operator.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/vvjEP5vW5).

As others have noted, template parameters on lambdas after the `[]` are on the `operator()`.

A template lambda like this:

```
template<std::size_t n>
auto some_lambda = [capture](auto&&...args) {
};
```

isn't allowed at non-global scope.

I suspect that is because the lifetime of such variable is a bit gonzo.  Does it come into existence if any branch of code could instantiate it when declared, or does it come into existence when first mentioned?  And they leave scope at the usual time?

It ends up being quite strange.  So I can see why they banned it.